# Where should I fill in my DNS records

Tags: domain-name-system

I have domain names spread over a lot of different registrars, and I have one place where I host all the websites.

The place where I host my website has an DirectAdmin panel where I can do some DNS configuration.

Now most of the registrars enable me to do my own DNS config at their panel, so I can fill in the MX records at 2 places, 1) in my DirectAdmin panel, 2) At my registrars control panel.

Now I do my email trough google, so I have to fill in the MX records for google, which is the best place to fill in these details, and where is the best place to create the ftp and www CNAME or A records.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would configure the registrar to use the web hosting DNS servers, then update the records only on the webhosting side. Much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever your nameservers for that domain point.